# basic TCP communication port related query

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, protocols

I have a GPS device which communicates to my server and server communicates back. Server accepts tcp connections on port 2224. The client connects to the server let us say from port 55545. I get the data from client and I have to send a string (in byte form) back.

1. My question is which port is used by server to send my string to the client (is it 2224) ?
2. and which port is used by the client to receive this data ( is it 55545)?

The person who manufactures the device just asks me to send the data back. Does not talk of ports. The server already has an option to send a reply to client device but it again does not speak of any ports so I cannot configure that.

Comment: Don't worry about ports (except of course the clients need to connect to the port that is listening, in your example 2224). They're not relevant to your problem and the port is assigned randomly anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is which port is used by server to send my string to the client (is it 2224)?

Irrelevant. Just send the response back on the same socket you received the request on.

> and which port is used by the client to receive this data ( is it 55545)?

Again it's irrelevant. The client reads the response via the same socket it used to send the request.

There is no API for sending or receiving data via ports, only via sockets, which are endpoints of a connection. In both cases it is the *connection* which is important, which is defined by the tuple {source IP address, source port, target IP address, target port}.

Comment: Thank you ..I get the idea now ..."There is no API for sending or receiving data via ports, only via sockets, which are endpoints of a connection"....is the magic words I was looking for..

Answer (score 3):

A TCP connection is bi-directional. If the device connects to your server to send data, just use that connection to talk back to it.